# CkEditor edit source code <strike> tag to <s> tag

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor version 3.6.4 and since `<strike>` tag is obsolete, I want to make the editor use `<s>` instead of it. I've managed to edit the `ckeditor.js` file and change this line: `i.coreStyles_strike={element:'strike'}` into this line `i.coreStyles_strike={element:'s'}` . which now allows me to add `<s></s>` tags when I press the Strikethrough button inside the editor( also visible in source mode), but if I save the changes they still don't show up on the website page.

Is there still something that blocks the usage of `<s>` tag?

My `config.js` file was empty and I tried adding

```
CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;
```

outside of the `CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {}` function
and `config.allowedContent = true;` inside this function. Both to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code.

```
CKEDITOR.config.coreStyles_strike = { element: 's', overrides: 'strike' };
```

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/commit/db6ffc3a857

Comment: Have already applied those changes... yet it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the content filtering and transformation that happens when the CK editor loads html. Your changes make it use `<s>` tags, but they are stripped or transformed when loading.

You need to configure the allowed contents like this:

```
config.allowedContent =
    'h1 h2 h3 p blockquote strong em;' +
    'a[!href];' +
    'img(left,right)[!src,alt,width,height];';
```

Go to the [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter-section-4) section of the CK Editor documentation to get full details with samples about this.

Comment: I also thought this might be happening, this is why I tried to disable the Content Filter by using 'config.allowedContent = true;' . It says on the documentation page that the value true disables the filter.

Comment: Do a test. Create a simple html with <s> and load it with CK editor. Inspect the element. You won't find <s>. Your content filtering still works after `CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;`

Comment: Indeed, that is true. After some research though, I've  found out that the Advanced Content Filter is actually part of Ckeditor version 4.1 and onward, whilst I have version 3.6.4 .

Comment: CKEditor removes some of your tags on loading. You don't need to change the source code to prevent this part since the process is configurable.